# Apple Watch WatchKit Swift - Stay Signed in after delete and reinstall of Watch App

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, watchconnectivity

So currently I am leveraging the watchConnectivity framework to send a token to my WatchKit app to authenticate the user.  This works perfectly! I then store this token in the watches keychain for future use, which works!

The issue I am facing is that apps like Starbucks and myFitnessPal allow the ability to:
1. Install watch app
2. log in on iOS app (sending token to watch app)
3. Now successfully signed in on watch app
4. uninstall watch app
5. re install watch app
6. with no other action other than opening the watch app they are still signed in to the watch app.

How is this being accomplished? my current understanding of WatchConnectivity framework is that it can only send and receive data, but how can I send data to the watch without ever opening the parent iOS app?

Comment: They're most probably storing the login info in keychain for instance. That way the watch app can simply retrieve the data from iCloud without having to communicate with the iOS app directly.

Comment: @DávidPásztor so I am also storing it in keychain, but that is wiped on app uninstall.  are you saying they are probably using NSKeyValueStore with iCloud? then fetching from there and THEN storing in keychain?

Comment: are you sure you are using keychain not nsuerdefault? keychain data will not be deleted even if you delete the app.

Comment: @coolioxlr is this true even for apple watch’s local key chain?  Currently i am saving to keychain, but it is not persistent through watch app uninstalls